# Is it possible to track mails sent?

Tags: shell-script, shell, email, sendmail

I am sending mails to many persons through a shell script.
I just want to track the mail and collect some information like time difference between sent mail and acknowdgement mail and process the data automatically through the shell script.
Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance,
Karthika

Comment: Please do not edit your question as a way to ask a new question. Instead use the [*ask a question*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) link to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

This depends heavily on two things

1. The MTA that you're using
2. What you mean by acknowledgement

If you're using something such as qmail, then each mail you put through mailx or /usr/lib/sendmail will generate a mail ID (queue ID). Each mail ID will have multiple delivery attempts, you can collate this.

Things get trickier when you talk about tracking. Are you expecting a delivery note? Are you expecting a read response from a human? Are you expecting an image to be loaded in the mail and this image to have a reference that you can track in your web server logs? What happens if this mail gets forwarded?

The only figure worth keeping track of would be when the mail leaves the queue, since there could be N mail servers involved once the mail is delivered to the next hop in the delivery process, it then becomes somebody else's responsibility.